# How to start two foreach loops dispatcher invoke simultaneously c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to display strings char by char in two labels at the same time using
two different Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() ?

I have two foreach loops like this:

```
        string str1 = "NUMBER OF PASSED:" + "\t\t" + passed1.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "NUMBER OF FAILED:" + "\t" + failed1.ToString();

        foreach (var ch1 in str1)
        {
            var char_by_char1 = ch1;
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {                    
                first_result.Content += char_by_char1.ToString();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
            }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
        }


        string str2 = "NUMBER OF PASSED:" + "\t\t" + passed2.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "NUMBER OF FAILED:" + "\t" + failed2.ToString();

        foreach (var ch2 in str2)
        {
            var char_by_char2 = ch2;
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                second_result.Content += char_by_char2.ToString();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
            }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
        }
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean: that code will work, but will show str1 in first_result before showing str2 in second_result.  Do you mean you want to interleave them (for which you just want one loop and to invoke twice in each loop)?  Why do you want to do it character-by-character with separate posts to the event loop??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not use TPL instead, like this:

```
var dispatcherObj = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

string str1 = "NUMBER OF PASSED:" + "\t\t" + passed1.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "NUMBER OF FAILED:" + "\t" + failed1.ToString();

var tsk1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
{
    foreach (var ch1 in str1)
    {
        var char_by_char1 = ch1;
        dispatcherObj.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {                    
            first_result.Content += char_by_char1.ToString();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
        }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
});


string str2 = "NUMBER OF PASSED:" + "\t\t" + passed2.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "NUMBER OF FAILED:" + "\t" + failed2.ToString();

var tsk2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
{
    foreach (var ch2 in str2)
    {
        var char_by_char2 = ch2;
        dispatcherObj.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            second_result.Content += char_by_char2.ToString();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
        }), DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
});
```

I am running the Loops on a Task/non UI thread, and posting the UI changes using Dispatcher.Invoke

Comment: Thank´s Prateek Shrivastava
That was exactly what i wanted :D

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.

But not like you're doing it there.

Dispatcher begininvoke will run your action on the UI thread.

That thread is the thing that does everything to do with the UI though. Including things you probably don't want to interrupt. Like displaying your new character.

As a rule of thumb.

Never sleep the UI thread, because it'll freeze the ui.

In this case the "other" invoke can't do anything because you burned the thread you're trying to run it on.  The first of those invokes that starts is the only thing will do anything for a while and you won't see the results before it has finished.

I suggest you remove the lines have:

```
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
```

There will now be no delay but your ui will not be frozen.

Make that action async.

Insert a line:

```
await Task.Delay(5);
```

Where that sleep was.

How long a delay were you expecting?

That 5 is 5 milliseconds.

Maybe you want 500 or 5000.

You're then freeing up that thread and you they should have a chance of behaving more like you expected.

Depending on exactly what you're trying to do, you might do better appending to a list of actions with each action changing a letter.

Then you could iterate through with the await task.delay to introduce a delay.